# How to generate new data with a VAE?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, keras, autoencoders, generative-models

I have built the following function which takes as input some data and runs a VAE on them:

```
def VAE(data, original_dim, latent_dim, test_size, epochs):
    
    x_train, x_test = train_test_split(data, test_size=test_size, random_state=42)
    
    # Define the VAE architecture
    #Encoder
    encoder_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(original_dim,))
    x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoder_inputs)
    x = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(x)

    #--- Custom Latent Space Layer
    z_mean = layers.Dense(units=latent_dim, name='Z-Mean', activation='linear')(x)
    z_log_sigma = layers.Dense(units=latent_dim, name='Z-Log-Sigma', activation='linear')(x)
    z = layers.Lambda(sampling, name='Z-Sampling-Layer')([z_mean, z_log_sigma, latent_dim]) # Z sampling layer

    # Instantiate the encoder
    encoder = tf.keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_sigma, z], name='encoder')

    #Decoder
    latent_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    x = layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
    x = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    decoder_outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)

    # Instantiate the decoder
    decoder = tf.keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name='decoder')

    # Define outputs from a VAE model by specifying how the encoder-decoder models are linked
    # Instantiate a VAE model
    vae = tf.keras.Model(inputs=encoder_inputs, outputs=decoder(encoder(encoder_inputs)[2]), name='vae')
    
    # Reconstruction loss compares inputs and outputs and tries to minimise the difference
    r_loss = original_dim * tf.keras.losses.mse(encoder_inputs, decoder(encoder(encoder_inputs)[2]))  # use MSE

    # KL divergence loss compares the encoded latent distribution Z with standard Normal distribution and penalizes if it's too different
    kl_loss = -0.5 * K.mean(1 + z_log_sigma - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_sigma), axis=-1)

    #VAE total loss
    vae_loss = K.mean(r_loss + kl_loss)

    # Add loss to the model and compile it
    vae.add_loss(vae_loss)
    vae.compile(optimizer='adam')
    
    # train the model
    vae.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

where

```
def sampling(args):
    
    z_mean, z_log_sigma, latent_dim = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mean)[0], latent_dim), mean=0., stddev=1., seed=42)
    return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_sigma) * epsilon
```

My question is, if I want to generate new data, by using the above VAE how can I achieve that ?

If I want to sample 100 new data, should I use this

```
   latent_mean = tf.math.reduce_mean(encoder(x_train)[2], axis=0) 
   latent_std = tf.math.reduce_std(encoder(x_train)[2], axis=0)
   tf.random.normal(shape=(100, latent_dim), mean=latent_mean, stddev=latent_std)
```

or

```
   latent_mean = tf.math.reduce_mean(encoder(x_train)[0], axis=0) 
   latent_std = tf.math.exp(tf.math.reduce_mean(encoder(x_train)[1], axis=0))
   tf.random.normal(shape=(100, latent_dim), mean=latent_mean, stddev=latent_std)
```

?

Basically, should I use the z_mean and z_log_sigma directly ? Or should I infer them from the z ?

Comment: The outputs of `normal` will be the same when the inputs are the same. But we have good reason to expect `z_log_sigma` to be on the log scale (your code uses exponentiation: `K.exp(z_log_sigma)`), and therefore different than `np.std(z)`.

Comment: You are right, that was a typo. I editted my question

Comment: The question remains though

Comment: I don't see any evidence of an edit (there's no edit history). But even if you switch `normal(mean=z_mean, stddev=z_log_sigma)` to `normal(mean=z_mean, stddev=np.exp(z_log_sigma))`, the output will still be different from `normal(mean=np.mean(z), stddev=np.std(z))` because the two calls have different inputs: the latter has scalar mean and standard deviation, but the former has an array. The documentation explains the distinction.

Comment: I see the confusion. I tried to oversimplify the question by removing the dimensions. I removed the confusing part. The bottomline of the question is if I should use directly the z_mean and z_log_sigma, or if I should infer them from Z. I do not understand the difference between these 2

Answer (score 2):

At a high level of abstraction, there are three steps to VAEs. (The most common use-case of a VAE assumes that the $z$ are distributed as a multivariate normal distribution with a diagonal covariance matrix, so I focus on that.)

1. **Encode**. Use a neural network $f$ to map the input $x$ to a vector means and a vector of standard deviations:  $f(x) = (\mu, \sigma)$
2. **Sample**. Draw a vector from the multivariate normal distribution defined by $(\mu, \sigma)$. This is $z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2 I)$.
3. **Decode**. Use a neural network to map the vector $z$ to something that "looks like" the input $x$. We could write this as $\hat x = g(z)$.

During, the loss is computed as the sum of the KLD and the reconstruction error: $\| \hat x - x \|_2^2 + KLD$, for example.

If you're trying to generate *new* data that "looks like" the input data, then you want $\hat x$. So neither of your proposals is correct -- you want to decode $z$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then I should do the following: `latent_sample = tf.random.normal(shape=(100, latent_dim), mean=latent_mean, stddev=latent_std)` and then `generated_data = decoder(latent_sample)`, right ? But then which `latent_mean` and `latent_std` should I use ?

Comment: To draw the latent variable $z$, you use the mean and standard deviation obtained from the encoder, `z_mean` and `exp(z_log_sigma)`

Comment: I do not understand what is the difference between `tf.math.reduce_mean(encoder(x_train)[2], axis=0)` (the mean of the latent vector z) and `tf.math.reduce_mean(encoder(x_train)[0], axis=0)` (the mean of the encoder).

I mean, isnt the distribution of $z$ as close as possible to the distribution of the input data, due to the KL divergence ? So, shouldnt these two be similar ? I guess I am missing something here

Comment: $z$ is the latent variable, an *encoding* of the input, but there's no requirement that the encoding has to be close to $x$. The whole point of the decoder is to transform $z$ into  $\hat x$, and the **reconstruction loss function** tells you how close the **reconstruction** $\hat x$ is to the input $x$. You can make the KL divergence exactly 0 if you use a $z$ that has nothing to do with the input, but does exactly match your desired distribution. The VAE loss is KLD *plus reconstruction loss*. Reconstruction loss is usually something like $\| \hat x - x \|_2^2$.

Comment: But isnt the desired distribution, the distribution of the original data ? I am confused

Comment: It seems that you do not have a strong understanding of VAEs. This is a good thread about what VAEs are and how they work. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321841/what-are-variational-autoencoders-and-to-what-learning-tasks-are-they-used/328181#328181